# Should I leave a self-QA open?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/158351/61218) yesterday, but when I was writing the answer, a comment from [izx](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx) was there, asking more details. Then a completed the answer, and told him that, I actually trying to share a find out. Though I was feeling shame or some uneasiness about the fact that, I should have give more time to other answerer to give the answer.

My question is: Should I really give more time for the interested answerer, or Was I OK in my procedure. I feel some uneasiness about that. I want to hear from community.

Comment: It also seems to me too localized, and Not a ideal question. So, I deleted the Q/A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask a question and not post it for answering immediately.  The system allows for you to create your own encyclopedic content, i.e. ask a question and answer it simultaneously.  For [both of my bug-](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153692/how-are-ubuntu-bugs-importance-values-decided)[related questions and self-answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153765/how-do-bugs-get-categorized-and-what-is-the-lifecycle-of-a-bug) I was able to write the question *and* the answer simultaneously, and then hit "Submit" and the question showed it was already immediately answered.  This feature has been in place for a while now.  Granted, the question will be open until you can mark it as answered, but the question and answer will be both posted simultaneously.

And I am a strong supporter of posting your own QAs, if you know what you're talking about ;)

Answer (score 2):

My opinion would be, by approaching with the idea for a question to be eligible for Bounty , it should be two days old .

So before Accepting answer which is Self-answered , i guess Giving that Two days Bounty eligibility days as time period for Interested Answerer , would be Better and Logical choice. It provides a fair share of getting a better or equivalent answer and also a cleared view of what should it contain from other answers whilst Self posting it .However,  sometimes they can be much better than you can add , so availability of chance matters.

Otherwise , you can put **P.S.** or **NOTE** or a comment stating that Answer from the Asker is also intended or Expected as in a Tutorial Format .So the interested Answerer could or would suggest the content in the answer(which ofcourse would be brief , and it also helps in gaining reputations from community, like a fair chance)  ,according to him. Thereby making it a better QA.

As Jeff Atwood said [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

> To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own
>   question, it is **explicitly encouraged**.
>
> I do it all the time! For example, when I ran into a nasty issue with
>   Java exploits in Google Chrome when browsing for images, I documented
>   that on Super User by asking and answering my own question. Now,
>   others can benefit from my misfortune — and **best of all, I got new
>   even better answers beyond what I offered! Overall, a huge win all
>   around.**

So availing a time period for interested answer would be good enough , or If you are Confident enough to post it as Answer and accept it quite soon, both are welcomed.

Comment: As far as I know, You cannot accept your own answer before 2 days period. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Please feel free to edit this , at the time of answering i was unaware of the two days waiting fact , my mistake. Or comment so , so i can delete this answer.

Comment: No need to delete this. The answer is good. and that little information missing is not a big fact for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The question is still "open": the system gives *at least 2 days* for other answerers before you can mark yours as "accepted".

That said, I think that particular question may be a little too localized or "thin" on content, but that's just my opinion.